# How to send parameter to ICommand 's Execute method

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I have gone through few MVVM examples in SL/WPF and the very basic thing here is to implement `ICommand` interface. I have understood how MVVM works. However, I have a doubt regarding `Execute` method of `ICommand` interface.

The class which implements `ICommand` has `Execute` method as shown below.

```cs
public void Execute(object parameter) //Method to call when the command is invoked
        {
          // pointer to a method to be executed
        }
```

In every example, I see that parameter in above method is `NULL`. Why? Can someone post a simple example of MVVM where this object parameter is put to use and not null ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the XAML you can set a CommandParameter

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="SomeData" />
```

Comment: AWESOME. I assume we can send any data here and not just string data.

Comment: @Nexus Yes, you can even use a binding on the `CommandParameter` to send it a bound value from the data layer